# Change Name Sorting of first and second Author

Tags: biblatex

i am struggling to correctly sort the names of the Authors in my bibliography. I am using `biblatex` with `numeric` cite- and bibstyle.

```
\usepackage[
citestyle=numeric,
bibstyle=numeric,
backend=bibtex,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
clearlang=true,
maxcitenames=3,
eprint=false,
url=false,
]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}

 \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \ifnumequal{\value{listtotal}}{2}{\addcomma\space}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}%
 }
```

Let's assume that I have 2 or more authors. The default of the university is: Last name, First name (first letter only), First name (first letter only) Last name. As a small example:

> Bai, Y., T. Wierzbicki

I know that this behavior is standard with `authoryear`. However, with `numeric` I don't know how to set it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the desired output with a combination of the `giveninits` option and code from `authoryear.bbx` to change the `sortname` format.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=numeric,
  backend=bibtex,
  maxcitenames=3,
  giveninits=true,
  doi=false,
  eprint=false,
  url=false,
  isbn=false,
  clearlang=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}


\DeclareDelimFormat{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}


\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,aksin,yoon,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E., U. Ryde.]

Comment: Great! Thank you.